# where did Google, SimpleGeo and such got their data about places and contexts?

Tags: geolocation, geonames

I wonder where did they got those data and then build web services/api on top to serve the other 3rd party apps and services. for example - given a user's lat and long data, they can return the places/venues nearby.

Comment: Yes did they start from scratch filling data with every place in the world?